# OpenTok: archiving in safari mode supported ?

Tags: opentok

We are developing a site that uses opentok.js library to do live streaming. We are using the "safari mode" since we have to support iOs devices(mobile Safari), Android devices (mobile Chrome) and desktop (Mac and Pc)(Safari or Chrome) devices. Does OpenTok archiving support archiving streams in this mode ?. Ideally we would like to have an mp4 file of one of the streams in a session archived. Are there limitations on browser versions for archiving ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, archiving will work in "Safari mode", for both composed and individual archives.

The only limitation is that, in "Safari mode", some android clients are not  able to send a compatible video, so those clients will not appear in the archive.

Comment: Thanks @Jose, the android clients that you mention that cannot send video, are they the ones that cannot encode the video to H.264 format ?

Comment: In my experience, the clients that cannot encode H.264 (some Android and versions of Firefox before 56) will still appear in the archive, but the files will be audio-only .webm instead of .mkv.